# How to statistically account for the different length of time patients were on the different drugs, as to compare the two groups in R?

Tags: r, regression, biostatistics, ancova

Conducting a statistical analysis of two groups of subjects being on different drugs. One group has stayed on drug A, while the other group switched to drug B from drug B at around the middle of the individual experiment time - for some subjects it would be 200 days, while for the others it is 1000.

In general, the subjects who stayed on drug A were on the drug longer than the group which switched.

I already know that there is a significant difference between the two lengths of specific drugs. Is there to predict the changes in the switch group prior to the comparison, and then analyse it? Possibly, **introduce it into the ANCOVA or the regression analysis**?

Is it possible to do in R?

Comment: Could you please proofread your question.

Answer (score -2):

You can do Independent Sample T-test. I am not sure what the codes are in R, but you can google it.

Comment: This post was improperly migrated from stats.stackexchange.com just because the author put R in the title by mistake.  Statistically speaking, the question cannot be answered without using highly complex methods with more assumptions because medication switching is a **dependent** variable.